# Do I need to use the same WT C57BL individual for back-crossing or can I use a new one for each generation?

Tags: mice

I've just received heterozygote C57BL mice from COMP and I need to start back-crossing them. I've read many colony management protocols, but couldn't understand if I need to use the same WT mouse for all ~10 generations of back-crossing or use a new one for each generation.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm totally unqualified for this, but if you used the same mouse to father 10 generations of mice, wouldn't you have mice that are nearly identical to the wt mouse? If the offspring get half of their DNA from the father, the 1st generation is 50% identical to him, 2nd is 75%, 3rd is 87.5% and so on with 10th at about 99.9% identical. So you might spend a lot of effort to get a WT mouse. I might be wrong too, never had to breed mice.

Comment: I do not think a single male stud mouse can remain active for 10 generations of mouse to become available for mating, taking the gestation period (~ 19-21 days) and the mating age (~ 6-8 weeks) into account (http://jaxmice.jax.org/support/husbandry/colony-planning.html). By my math for 10 generations that is ([21+56]x10) 770 days.